# Rails 3 - How do create counter cached column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I make a counter cachce column for tags (Count how many konkurrancer that belongs to a tag) And how do I make a task that update the counters on delete and when creating a new konkurrancer. And a task to update all counters. Instead of typing them manually first.

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tagsmenus, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :tags, :through => :tagsmenus
end
```

My model:

```
class Tagsmenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :konkurrancer
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tagsmenus
has_many :konkurrancers, :through => :tagsmenus
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (was, I haven't checked 3.1) not builtin.

But see a really nice blog post [here](http://whilefalse.net/2011/04/05/rails-3-counter-cache-has_many-through/), you'll be able to implement it directly following the advice there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to make the "counter cache column" but once you have it in place, you can manipulate it with various filters in your controller. check out this guide on [controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)